# IntelliJ Idea - TypeScript + JSPM support

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript, jspm

My IntelliJ Idea does not resolve TypeScript modules that I installed via JSPM.
For example angular2 is not found.

Is there a way to get support for those imports?

I am using this version of IntelliJ Idea:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.1
Build #IU-145.597, built on March 29, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b18 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18904) posted in the JetBrains Youtrack targeting the JSPM support.